# Como obtener etiquetas de gráfico chart en itextsharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

Tengo el siguiente gráfico Chart en asp.net. Mas abajo tengo un botón que lo convierte a un PDF. Mi problema surge cuando genero el pdf y no me muestra las etiquetas con sus respectivos valores sobre cada barra(imagen 2).

[image: imagen 1]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No pongas el código con una foto, intenta siempre poner el código en la pregunta escrito para que los usuarios puedan copiarlo y hacer pruebas con él.

Comment: No solo que alguien pueda copiar el código... estoy en la red de empresa y no puedo ver las imágenes! ¡Ni siquiera puedo ver el código!